# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? idCursos)
{
    var usuarios = db.Usuario.ToList();
    if(!(idCursos == null))
    {
        usuarios = from Usuario in db.Usuario
                                from Relaciones in db.Relaciones
                                where Relaciones.Cursos.idCurso == idCursos
                                select new
                                {
                                    Nombre = Usuario.Nombre,
                                    Apellido = Usuario.Apellido,
                                    Usuario.DNI,
                                };

    }
    return View(usuarios);
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<LibreriaEntidad.Usuario>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: I have try that, I change de query name to "Query" and then write, usuarios = query.ToList(); but the error is the same. "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<LibreriaEntidad.Usuario>' "

Comment: That's because of your `select new { }`, which introduces an anonymous type. Either remove that, or store the query into a new variable and return that one to your view.

Comment: thats the answer i was looking for thanks, so i should put select new usuario?

Comment: Excuse me, I misread. You seem to want to return two different types of results from this method, which is not possible. What exactly do you want to return if a user passes `idCursos`?

Comment: a Usuarios object that fits that "where"

Comment: Then just `select Usuario.ToList()` instead of `select new {...}`, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will get you close.. I'm not sure how you have your relationships set up, but if `Usuario >> Relaciones >> Cursos` then you can do something like this..

```
public ActionResult Index(int? idCursos)
{
    var model = db.Usuario;
    if (idCursos.HasValue)
    {
        model = model.Where(a => a.Relaciones.Any(a => a.Cursos.idCurso == idCursos));
    }
    return View(model.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I belive you just need to call `.ToList()` on your LINQ Query

```
        usuarios = from Usuario in db.Usuario
                                     from Relaciones in db.Relaciones
                                     where Relaciones.Cursos.idCurso == idCursos
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         Nombre = Usuario.Nombre,
                                         Apellido = Usuario.Apellido,
                                         Usuario.DNI,
                                     }.ToList();
```

Comment: Nope, that'll give "Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.List<LibreriaEntidad.Usuario>."